# Insert foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

So i get this error :

> **Notice:** Uninitialized string offset

I want to insert the value of the checked radio button of the radio button set at each row of my table .

That mean at every row of my table i have this Question ll Radio button set ll Commentary .

A survey form .

```
<?php
$link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
$un = 0;
$msgerror = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs ";    
if(isset($_POST["bouton10"])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST["Picolo4"];
    $Nom = $_REQUEST["Picolo1"];
    $Prenom = $_REQUEST["Picolo2"];
    $Email = $_REQUEST["Picolo3"];

    if ($id !="" && $Nom !="" && $Prenom !="" && $Email !="") {
        $recherche= "SELECT Ref,Question,Choix,Commentara FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id'";
        mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
        $result= mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
        $num_results = $result->num_rows;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $Ref =$row["Ref"];
            $Question =$row["Question"];
            $un++;

            echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">
                <td>$Question position: $un </td>
                <td>
                    <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">
                    <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"2\">
                    <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"1\">
                    <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\"  value = \"0\">
                    <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"0\">
                </td>
                <td width = \"60\"> <textarea> </textarea> </td> 
            </tr>                              
            </div>
            </div>"; 
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgerror')</script>";
    }
}
//The part with the problem //
$un = 1;
if (isset($_POST["bouton11"])) {
    $i= 0 ;  
    while(isset($_POST[$un])) {
        //Line 71 //
        $choix = $_POST["$un"][$i];
        $enregistrer = "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix)  VALUES('$choix') ";
        $un++;
        $i++;
        mysqli_query($link, $enregistrer);
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It's most likely because the `$_REQUEST[x]` value doesn't exist, try something like `$id = !empty($_REQUEST["Picolo4"]) ? $_REQUEST["Picolo4"] : "";` **BUT** please sanitize your inputs and use prepared statements. Your code is really vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: What's the full error? It should show you what line is consing this, thus, you can check what index you are trying to read, that is not there yet. Ie,  `$choix = $_POST["$un"][$i]` also looks suspicios

Comment: the full error : Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Foredeck\foredeckaffiche_client.php on line 71 that mean yes the part '' $choix = $_POST["$un"][$i];"

Comment: Add check in foreach loop: if (! isset($_POST["$un"][$i])) { continue; }

Comment: could you rewrite me the code please ? it s kind of hard to understand , i m a student and new to php .

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Then you could show me on my code please  because   i m new to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST["$un"]` might be

> 3,2,1,0 or 0.

And then you're trying to access `$_POST["$un"][$i]` while `$i` is an incresing number. When you try to treat a string as an array - the `[$i]` would access it's characters, but your string has only 1 character and your loop keeps on running for each `$_POST` key exists which is more than 1 time obviously.

For instance:

```
$string = "abcd";
echo $string[0]; // a
echo $string[1]; // b
echo $string[5]; // Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 5 in ..
```

So you will need to modify your loop.
Instead of using:

```
foreach ($_POST as $val){
```

Try to use:

```
while(isset($_POST[$un])){
   //your code here
   $un++; //don't forget to increase $un
}
```

**Update 1:**

There's no reason in trying to treat $_POST[$un] as an array so replace this:

```
$choix = $_POST["$un"][$i];
```

with:

```
$choix = $_POST["$un"];
```

Comment: Ok let me explain my self , i m doing a survey that generate automaticaly a radio button set and a commentary text area if you have a question or many question in the survey . The purpose is to not need to change code everytime when you add a question to the survey but generate it .  That mean I got a question then ==> generate radio button set then ==> generate text area . So that  s why i m using in the same time a variable for radio button set to not get conflict beetween others radio button set .

Comment: Try to follow the update of my answer and modify your loop.

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\Foredeck\foredeckaffiche_client.php on line 71. So i need to do a string for every values of every radio button set ?

Comment: Can you please update your new code in the question and mark which line is 71?

Comment: Check **Update 1** in my answer.